# ASP.site_master' does not contain a definition for 'HeadLoginView_ViewChanged'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

The whole message is:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.site_master' does not contain a
>   definition for 'HeadLoginView_ViewChanged' and no extension method
>   'HeadLoginView_ViewChanged' accepting a first argument of type
>   'ASP.site_master' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
>   an assembly reference?)

What Doesn't it like?  I am working in the Site.Master and the code below is there.

```
<asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" onviewchanged="HeadLoginView_ViewChanged">
    <AnonymousTemplate>
        [ <a href="~/Account/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
    </AnonymousTemplate>
    <LoggedInTemplate>
        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="Default.aspx"/> ]
    </LoggedInTemplate>
</asp:LoginView>
```

Comment: Can you post your code behind page? The compiler is looking for the method `HeadLoginView_ViewChanged` because it is being referenced on the `OnViewChanged event` of the `asp:LoginView`

Answer (score 1):

This would happen if you have a syntax error in your codebehind, or if you deleted the handler.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have a matching method to catch the event.  That's always the error when I've experienced it.  Make sure the name matches 100% what's in markup.